# How not to overwrite an existing data in MAP c++?

Tags: c++

Currently I'm facing a big problem where I need to populate data to MAP and write it to the file.

The file will look something like this:

```
Name   StudentNo  Gender Indian English  Math  History  Moral  Average
Dragon    33899     M     100      100    100    100     100      100
```

Here's the code

```
  //  Function to modify a student's exam scores.
    void Student::modifyScore(string newName, int newStudentNo, char newGender,  int newIndian, int newEnglish, int newMath, int newHistory, int newMoral) {


    map<string, tuple<int, char,int, int, int, int, int> > data;

    // Read file and fill data map
    ifstream studentRec("StudentRecord.txt");
    string line;

    while (getline(studentRec, line))
    {
       string name;
       int studentNo;
       char gender;
       int indian, english, math, history, moral;
       stringstream ss(line);
       ss >> studentNo>>gender>>name >> indian >> english >> math >> history >> moral;
       data[name] = make_tuple(studentNo, gender,indian, english, math, history, moral);

    }

    studentRec.close();
    auto it = data.find(newName) ;
    if (it == data.end()) // student not in map, that's an error
      return ;   
    // now it->second holds your student data,
    int studentNo = get<0>(data-second) ;
    char gender = get<1>(data->second) ;
    // Modify data
    data[newName] = make_tuple(newStudentNo, newGender ,newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral);
    // Open same file for output, overwrite existing data
    ofstream ofs("StudentRecord.txt");

    for (auto entry = data.begin(); entry != data.end(); ++entry)
    {
        tie(newStudentNo, newGender,newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral) = entry->second;
        int average = averageScore(newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral);

        ofs << left <<  setw(15) << entry->first << setw(15) <<newGender<<newName<< newIndian << setprecision(2) << newEnglish << setw(15) << right << newMath << setw(15) << newHistory << setw(15) <<  newMoral << average << endl;
    }
    ofs.close();


}
```

The problem with this code is that I have to add **studentNo** and **gender** as the argument of the function then only it would overwrite the file, but what I really want is to just enter a name, and then modify each subject scores.

Example what I really want.

**Before any modification**

```
   Name   StudentNo  Gender Indian English  Math  History  Moral  Average
    Dragon    33899     M     100      100    100    100     100      100
```

**The prompter**

```
Enter the name of the student: // It will find the map that has name Dragon
  --> Dragon

Enter the new score for indian subject
  -->  77

Enter the new score for English subject
  -->  55

Enter the new score for Math subject
  -->  100

Enter the new score for History subject
  -->  89

Enter the new score for Moral subject
  -->  62
```

**After modification**

```
     Name   StudentNo  Gender Indian English  Math  History  Moral  Average
     Dragon   33899      M      77      55    100    89       62      76.6
```

As you can see the **studentNo** and **gender** will still be there, without me needing to input the values. The only thing that have changed is the subject scores. How would I accomplish this output? currently my code will always needed me enter the input for **studentNo** and **gender** as well.

Comment: `data[newName]` overwrites the same key on every iteration of the loop since you never change it.

Comment: But how do i persist studentNo and gender value for a specifit student key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given name you can get an iterator to that student and then get original data

```
auto it = data.find(name) ; // gets current student record from the map
if (it == data.end()) // student not in map, that's an error
     return ;   
// now it->second holds your student data
// an auto here could be better, but we want to be sure of type
studentNo = get<0>(it->second) ;
gender = get<1>(it->second) ;
```

Comment: I get sorts of error, check my modify code again, i change name to newName because name has to be initialize first. <get>  --> no instance of overloaded function "get" matches argument list (the error)

Comment: The code has to be inserted *after* you ave read the input file. Keep in mind also suggestion from Retired Ninja. get<> is part of std::tuple header (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Comment: I already include tuple, but for some reason I still get error, and could you please elaborate the code a little bit, because I'm really confused right now.

Comment: While I try to elaborate post compiler error somewhere

Comment: looks ok, you also have included the other suggestion. Does the compiler still complains?

Comment: The compiler only complains about the get<> and data->second

Comment: Your edited code, why do I need to create a new tuple? can it just be based on the data tuple?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81100/discussion-between-marom-and-airsoftfreak).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose  you want to update StudentNo for the student record with name 'Dragon' you can do as follows:

```
int NewStudentNo;
string NewName="Dragon";

auto it = data.find(NewName) ; // gets current student record from the map
if (it == data.end()) // student not in map, that's an error
     return ;   
std::cout<<"Enter new student Number";
std::cin>>NewStudentNo;
std::get<0>(it->second) = NewStudentNo;
```

Comment: But what if I don't want to update studentNo and gender?,  what I need to update are just the subjects

Comment: Change the index accordingly, for example for Indian `get<2>(it->second)=newIndian`